# Android Navigation drawer with Tab

Tags: android, tabs, navigation, drawer

Hello Guys can anyone guide me that why I am not getting the tabs, I don't have any idea to implement this one for your reference I am using android studio 2.1.2 and have used the the navigation drawer from template. For the tab I am using android hive code. Please find here my main_activity.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout                                     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I hope will have some solution. Thank You.

Again When I change the code like below the tabs show on the top but not able to click:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:id="@+id/appBar_layout">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And Here is my mainactivity.java File:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        /** Tablayout with View Pager **/
        private TabLayout tabLayout;
        private ViewPager viewPager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            /** Tab **/

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            setupViewPager(viewPager);

            tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
                // Handle the camera action
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }

        private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
            adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
            adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
            private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
            private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

            public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
                super(manager);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return mFragmentList.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mFragmentList.size();
            }

            public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
                mFragmentList.add(fragment);
                mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
            }
        }
    }
```

[You can see the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th9Z6.png)

Now I update the file but can't see the hamburger icon and title the rest of the work have been done.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:id="@+id/appBar_layout">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[You can see the result image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goTya.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your layout should be like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http:/`/schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/appBar_layout">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                .....
                ..../>
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Secondly, in order for the tabs to work, you need to use a `ViewPager Adapater`, andd then use `tabs.setupWithViewPager()`.
I recommend you look at [this](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/) tutorial to help you.

Comment: Yes I have but not able to click tabs.

Comment: 1. Did you organize the layout like I wrote? 2. Did you setup with viewpager?

Comment: Yes but the tabs are on the title bar and I not able to click them.

Comment: 1. Do you see the text on the different tabs? 2. What happens when you click on the tabs? Does it change the indicator? 3. Please show your Java code.

Comment: I can see the tabs title but when I click on them no thing happening. It doesn't change indicator too.

Comment: Please post your updated xml layout and your Java code.

Comment: Check my question there is java file.

Comment: Please change your xml layout to be exactly like I changed it, and see if it works.

Comment: I have changed the layout using you post and please see above the question there is image link what exactly its seems.

Comment: I edited the xml layout in my answer. Try it now. That way, the tabs don't overlap with the toolbar.

Comment: Now I am not getting Navigation Drawer.

Comment: Update your answer with your current xml layout please.

Comment: The second xml file is updated file I am not getting hamburger icon and title only.

Comment: Remove this:  <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Comment: Did it work? I'm pretty sure that when you remove the "include" it will work.

Comment: The reason is that now you have two toolbars by mistake, and the one in the "include" covers the first one with the navigation drawer toggle (hamburger).